# Array.sort(): Comparable's compareTo() only takes one argument?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

Here's a good one for all you out there; I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure this one out:

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by layer using `Array.sort()` and following a tutorial on another stack overflow post, I tried this code:

```
Arrays.sort(gameobj, new Comparator<GameObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(GameObject o1, GameObject o2) {
        return o1.layer.compareTo(o2.layer);
    }});
```

This code makes sense to me, but the problem is, the interface only accepts one argument for the `compare()` method. I've tried lambda expressions too, but that throws a "delete this token" compilation error. I'm using Java 8. Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: Huh?  `Comparator.compare` takes **two** arguments.

Comment: what type is _`layer`_?

Comment: I don't understand, but compare method has two arguments

Comment: Please show us the code that you have a question on, the one where you are using `Array.sort()`. It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(gameobj, Comparator.comparing(GameObject::getLayer));` should suffice given that `getLayer` is a type that implements `Comparable`

Comment: 'layer' is a standard integer.

Comment: You mean `int`? You can't call methods on a primitive type. Try `Integer.compare()`.

Comment: @hjk321 if you use the solution I mentioned above then it would work regardless if it's an `int` or `Integer` due to boxing. However, if you proceed with your approach and you're dealing with `int` the call `o1.layer.compareTo(o2.layer);` would fail.

Comment: @Aominè If it is an `int`, it would be preferable to use `Comparator.comparingInt()`.

Comment: So apparently I mixed up "Comparable" and "Comparator." Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A concise shorthand

The most concise way to do create a comparator from the comparable output returned by a method of your class is the following:

```
Arrays.sort(gameobj, Comparator.comparing(GameObject::getLayer));
```

### Another solution: implement Comparable

In your case, you may as well want to implement `Comparable` directly and delegate the comparison to the `Layer` class:

```
public class GameObject implements Comparable<GameObject> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(GameObject that) {
        return this.getLayer().compareTo(that.getLayer());
    }
}

Arrays.sort(gameobj);
```

### When to use Comparable vs Comparator

- `Comparable` is for implementing a natural order on a class. If your class naturally comes with an order relationship that anyone would expect from it, then `Comparable` is a good fit for you.
- `Comparator` is better for specific sorting logic in specific use-cases. It allows you to dissociate the way you want to sort elements in a particular context from the class the elements itself. It is more flexible because you can provide any number of comparators in any number of contexts whereas you can only implement `Comparable` once for a given class.

Answer (score 1):

Because a [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is for comparing two elements `a` and `b` where `a` is the implementing `Object`. If you're using `Comparable` then you don't need to pass a `Comparator` to the `Arrays.sort` method (it will use the instances themselves to perform the comparisons).

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of comparing in Java.

**Comparator** - accepts 2 argument, it is decoupled from the model, you can have multiple comparators to compare according to different cases. It's more dynamic.

**Comparable** - this is an interface, and your model (entity) has to implement method, that will compare itself with another entity of same type. This is less flexible, but provides you a 'default' sort method. The downside of this is that you cannot change it in runtime.

So your Arrays.sort, same like Lists.sort take an additional parameter -comparator, so that you can choose which Comparator to use in runtime :

```
Arrays.sort(gameobj, Comparators.comparing(GameObject::getLayer))
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can refactor your code as follow:**

```
Arrays.sort(gameobj, Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

**EDITED:** This is a solution if the gameobj's objects implement Comparable interface.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention that `GameObject` implements `Comparable`

Comment: And if it did, you don't even need to pass a comparator.